# __NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]in objective-c

Tags: ios, xcode

```
  if(counter>=keys.count){

        NSLog(@"finished");
        [_images removeFromSuperview];
      //  [_alphabetsShowImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [_speakerOrMicImageView removeFromSuperview];
        UIImageView *congratzView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        congratzView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"congratulation.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:congratzView];

    }

    else{


           arrVal = [dictAlpha objectForKey:keys[i]];


                 if(j>=arrVal.count)

                     {
                         NSLog(@"finished");
                         [_alphabetsShowImageView removeFromSuperview];
                         [_speakerOrMicImageView removeFromSuperview];
                         UIImageView *congratzView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
                         congratzView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"congratulation.png"];
                         [self.view addSubview:congratzView];
                       //  [self performSelector:@selector(navNew) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         [commonFunctionObject textToSpeechAction:arrVal :j :_alphabetsShowImageView :_speakerOrMicImageView :isMicPresent];
                         [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(ActionToCkeckRecordCompletion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                     }





           }








}
```

output i need-
    counter<=keys.count
 then it must enter to if statement condition ,
then  j<=arrval.count
    then enter to else condition .or then enter to if condition loop.
then if counter>=keys.count
then  it must enter to if statement condition

Answer (score 0):

You are using `counter` to iterate but you are accessing the array element with a different variable.

Your error clearly means that both counter and the accessors `i` & `j` may or may not be equal to counter.

Your code qualifies to be called a fast traversal. You might also consider enumeration for this scenario, will save you from the pain of maintaining a counter; and you can also avoid if-else statement. Helps one keep the code simple !

```
for(NSString* key in dictAlpha) {
    arrVal= [dictAlpha objectForKey:key];
}
```